# Creating a universal spoiler box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#spoil").click(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
  });
});
```

I am using Jquery to create a spoiler or drop down box so you click the button then the information disappears then when you click it again it comes back. I am planing on having many of these and was wondering how to transform my code so it would work with all the spoiler boxes with out needing to alter the js each time. Thank you

I am only after the content of the box being toggled not the button it self.

Comment: Do you really want multiple boxes or is it just the content of the spoiler that needs to be changed? i.e.: would a data driven solution work for you?

Comment: I want to the content of the div to be toggled not the button.

Comment: This is getting pretty confusing  cause you explained really bad your needs. Everybody is guessing what you actually need. I think it's time to show some HTML example of what you need and clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VWCnd/)

```
$(function() {
    $(".toggle").on("click",function() {
        $(".toggled").toggle().removeClass("toggled");
        $(this).next(".spoiler").toggle().addClass("toggled");
    })
});
```

Using a link I would add preventDefault:

```
$(function() {
    $(".toggle").on("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // do not follow the link
        $(".toggled").toggle().removeClass("toggled");
        $(this).next(".spoiler").toggle().addClass("toggled");
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a class, `.spoil`, instead of an ID, `#spoil`, then you can have as many elements with the `.spoil` class as you'd like.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".spoil").click(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="spoil"></div>
<div class="spoil"></div>
<div class="spoil"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but how can i make it so when you click the button or .spoil that all of it closes except for the button. So you can still toggle it. If that makes sense

Comment: How can you click something that has been toggled off?

Comment: @reidjako - sure, to do that you can update your JS and HTML to something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LpYvb/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are just needing to use classes, rather than an id. Using id's is generally not necessary or recommended.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".spoil").click(function(){ //bind a click function to all elements with class "spoil"
    $(this).toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you but how can i make it so when you click the button or .spoil that all of it closes except for the button. So you can still toggle it. If that makes sense

Comment: I have no ideal what you mean by "all of it". If you want more in-depth help, you should make a test on something like jsbin.com. I could take a look at it and show you how to make it work.

Comment: How can you click something that has been toggled off?